# How to Send full phone number to Api - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to send the full phone number (Country code and the phone number), but it seems to be a problem. The code is only sending the number without the country code and the plus sign. Somebody help. I am using the `intl_phone_number_input` package

The codes are all on different files and I am also using Get X for state management

Here is the Widget

```
 CustomPhoneInput(
  controller: otpController.controller,
   label: "Phone Number",
    )
```

Then the Phone input

```
  Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.sizeLarge),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(
          color: kBorder,
          width: 2.0,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.sizeMiniSmall),
      ),
      child: InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
        onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
          print(number.phoneNumber);
        },
        onInputValidated: (bool value) {
          print(value);
        },
        textStyle: sfRegular.copyWith(
            fontSize: Dimensions.sizeDefault, color: Colors.black),
        selectorTextStyle: sfRegular.copyWith(
            fontSize: Dimensions.sizeDefault, color: Colors.black),
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        ignoreBlank: true,
        countries: const ["KE", "UG", "TZ", "NG"],
        spaceBetweenSelectorAndTextField: 0,
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
        autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
        initialValue: PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'KE'),
        textFieldController: controller,
        inputBorder: InputBorder.none,
        formatInput: false,
        searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.search),
          prefixIconColor: kDarkGray,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: Dimensions.sizeExtraSmall,
            vertical: Dimensions.sizeExtraSmall,
          ),
          hintText: 'Search Country',
          hintStyle: sfRegular.copyWith(
              fontSize: Dimensions.sizeDefault, color: kDarkGray),
          enabledBorder: myinputborder(),
          focusedBorder: myfocusborder(),
        ),
        selectorConfig: const SelectorConfig(
          selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.BOTTOM_SHEET,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

And then the controller

```
class OtpController extends GetxController {
final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
 var loading = false.obs;

Future<void> submitPhone(BuildContext context) async {
try {
  loading.value = true;
  print(controller.text);
  var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

  var url = Uri.parse(
      ApiEndpoints.baseUrl + ApiEndpoints.authEndpoints.checkPhone);
  Map body = {
    'Phone': controller.text,
  };

  http.Response response =
      await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(body), headers: headers);
  final json = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(json);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    if (json['success'] == true) {
    } else {
      throw json['message'] ?? 'Something went wrong';
    }
  }
} catch (e) {
  CustomToast.show(
    e.toString(),
    context,
    backgroundColor: kErrorText,
    textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  );
} finally {
  loading.value = false; // set the loading state to false after the request
}
```

}
}

Comment: so this "print(controller.text);" only shows number without country code?

Comment: Yes, it prints the number without code

Comment: I haven't used this library, and their documentation seems bad. What you can do (super dumb solution) is get controller.countryCode() this will give you values like "US", "NG" then use a translator array. translator = [["TRY", "+90"], ["KZ", "+7"]] etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package itself is assigning the number only to the controller without the country code.

you don't need to assign the **TextEditingController** to the **InternationalPhoneNumberInput** widget.
instead, when the value changes, assign it to your **TextEditingController**

Like this:

```
Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.sizeLarge),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(
          color: kBorder,
          width: 2.0,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.sizeMiniSmall),
      ),
      child: InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
        onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
          controller.text=number.phoneNumber!;
          print(number.phoneNumber);
        },
        onInputValidated: (bool value) {
          print(value);
        },
        textStyle: sfRegular.copyWith(
            fontSize: Dimensions.sizeDefault, color: Colors.black),
        selectorTextStyle: sfRegular.copyWith(
            fontSize: Dimensions.sizeDefault, color: Colors.black),
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        ignoreBlank: true,
        countries: const ["KE", "UG", "TZ", "NG"],
        spaceBetweenSelectorAndTextField: 0,
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
        autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
        initialValue: PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'KE'),
        inputBorder: InputBorder.none,
        formatInput: false,
        searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.search),
          prefixIconColor: kDarkGray,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: Dimensions.sizeExtraSmall,
            vertical: Dimensions.sizeExtraSmall,
          ),
          hintText: 'Search Country',
          hintStyle: sfRegular.copyWith(
              fontSize: Dimensions.sizeDefault, color: kDarkGray),
          enabledBorder: myinputborder(),
          focusedBorder: myfocusborder(),
        ),
        selectorConfig: const SelectorConfig(
          selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.BOTTOM_SHEET,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```